# Why is there captcha after forgetting to add tags?

Tags: support, tags, asking-questions, captcha

The captchas got a lot worse to read. I have to reload them 2-3 times to get something I'm sure that I read correctly.

When entering new question, I often forget to add-tags. After adding them, I always get a captcha.

Is this necessary?

---

Edit:

Happened again because I had to edit tags (no 'bug feature-request discussion support').

Comment: The CAPTCHAS has gotten harder to read on any site that has them like http://co.cc/ has gotten harder to read and other sites including any SE site.

Answer (score 1):

I have requested legible captchas already.

Perhaps we should get the captcha the same time as the post rather than after it. And the request to add tags, rather than getting corrected later when we save the question.

Those of us who are blocked from asking questions should also be informed of this before we type it out, but that's another matter.

Answer (score 0):

I would a assume that a bot is more likely to just try and post the question without adding any tags - hence the recaptcha when posting after adding them.